# Integrate Gmail and Google Calendar with login

Tags: gmail, google, google-calendar, embed

Is there a way to get an embedded version of Gmail / Google Calendar with login?
(like the one on iGoogle)

I did find how to embed a calendar... but I want to see my very own calendar.
(Writing an own start page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only embed one calendar in a gadget at once, so unless all your events in your Google Calendar is under one single calendar, or else it is not going to be possible.

You can experiment with `<iframe>`, though it is a rather old and hacky way to get things working.